# Disable Anonymous Contributions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, site-policy, suggested-edits

**Note**: Due to my position as a moderator I can't comment or point to specifics, which greatly obfuscates the validity of my question.

The moderator team has been brought aware of certain irregularities around anonymous/unregistered contributions. We feel the situation is causing unneeded work for our curators. Due to the nature of unregistered contributors, we can not reach out and teach the users.

At the site level we can disable:

1. unregistered accounts posting, and/or
2. anonymous users editing posts.

Please vote on the options below. If the results are ambiguous the moderator team with take definitive action.

Comment: That is really a good plan. 
I personally fully adhere to what you say.
I hope it will be implemented soon.

Comment: This is done -- anonymous users can no longer edit posts. Apologies for the delay in fulfillment of this request.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Disable anonymous users editing posts

Comment: This is also very useful. Multiple times, I saw vandalism (on posts) because this is not implemented.

Comment: Related, almost 2 years ago: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10746/blocking-an-anonymous-user-from-proposing-edits

Answer (score 7):

## Disable unregistered accounts posting

Comment: I do not even understand why anonymous people are allowed to post: if I am interested in a given programming community, the comm sense is to create a profile and join. But if I have malevolent intentions, I will not join that community; and I will remain anonymous, so that I can create nuisances at will (using Tor browser, for example)

Comment: @BillalBegueradj Anonymity can cause a pretty obvious attack vector for bad actors. However, many users on Code Review post under 'fake names', a form of anonymity. A site which wants to maximise activity sees the trade off, more anonymous contributors for some bad actors. If the site sees an increase in bad actors to the point the scale tips, then processes are put in place to balance the scales. The approach of "anonymity == bad" ban anonymity; minimises bad actors but doesn't attempt to maximise good ones. I support the option here to balance the scale.

Comment: Sorry, my wording is misleading: by **anonymity** I meant **unregistered users**. It does not matter to be registered with a pseudonyme: registration will make it difficult to create new accounts (Gmail will prevent a user creating multiple profiles on the same device after a certain number, for example. So it will be easy to ban users based on their email address -which is already the case)

Comment: @BillalBegueradj I know. Doesn't change the answer to "I do not even understand why anonymous people are allowed to post".

Comment: @BillalBegueradj Most of the spammers we get nowadays use gmail, so clearly their system isn't without its flaws either. But forcing users to register does raise the bar of participation a bit. Which is a good thing or a bad thing, depending on who you ask.